# Return value as -0 from oracle sql

Tags: javascript, oracle

is there any way to return `0` as `-0` from oracle sql/plsql so that we can do some validation , this is just to make sure if the value 0 is rounded from a negative value or positive value.

If there is any alternate approach, to handle this , please let me know, rounding the value in Javascript is not exactly as rounding in oracle sql.

Comment: Where did the rounding happen? Can you select the non-rounded (presumably still negative) value instead? And what is "not exact" when rounding the value in Javascript? Maybe you can select both the rounded and the original value and look at the sign of the latter to decide what you want to do?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused: are you retrieving a -0 from oracle and want to round to 0 in javascript?

Comment: rounding happens in oracle procedure, now it will send as `0`, but in javascript we have do some code if the value is rounded to zero from -0.0000001 it should be displayed as red font zero else blue zero.

Comment: Sounds like you can select the unrounded value (in addition to the rounded one, if you don't want to round in Javascript for some reason).

Comment: @GJCode, we receive data as 0 from oracle but depends on if it rounded from a negative value , we should do some operation

Comment: What is `-0` anyway? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667577/does-negative-zero-exist

Comment: @A_T According to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-33A52FDB-BA5C-474E-96D3-40390BA5F5F4) there is no `-0` in Oracle: "The floating-point data types do not conform to IEEE754 in the following areas:  -0 is coerced to +0."  You may need to accept a workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my answer is do not round in Oracle: if javascript receives a 0 it can not know if it was -0.001 or +0.001 so keep it simple, pass the exact value to js and do something like this:

```
if(value < 0) {
doSomethin();
} else {
doElse();
```

if for some reason you have to round it in Oracle you have to give back some more info to js like: 0 "from negative" and in js:

```
if(text === "from negative") {
 doSomething();
} else {
doElse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below way to get your condition satisfied.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN 0=0 THEN '-0' ELSE 'FALSE' END) AS CHK_ZERO FROM DUAL;
```

In the above statement replace one zero with your **parameterized** variable and get the result as required.